# Flutter async programming

Tags: asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

After *using* a dataset I want to check how many datasets are *unused*. If I'm above the threshold I want to fetch new data.

```
useQuestion(Question question) async {
    print("using question $question");
    question.used=1;
    final db = await database;
    int count = await db.rawUpdate(
    'UPDATE Question SET used = ? WHERE question = ?',
    [question.used,question.question]);
    print(question);
    print("Made $count changes");
    var questions = await _checkQuestionThreshold();
    print(questions);
    for (var q in questions) {
        newQuestion(Question.fromJson(q));
      }
  }
```

**Check Threshold**

```
_checkQuestionThreshold() async {
print("count questions...");
final db = await database;
var res = await db.query("Question");
int count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(
    await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Question'));
int countUsed = Sqflite.firstIntValue(
    await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Question where used="1"'));
int i = 0;
if (count < 1 || (countUsed / count) < 0.5) {
  print("Okay... we fetch new...");



  return await _fetchFromFirebase();
}
```

**Fetching from DB:**

```
_fetchFromFirebase() async {
    var questionJson;
     databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) async {
        questionJson = await snapshot.value;
      }).catchError((e) {
        print(e);
      });
      return questionJson;
  }
```

However I get the following error when calling `for (var q in questions) {
        newQuestion(Question.fromJson(q));
      }` and I'm wondering what exactly I am missing.

```
I/flutter ( 5150): count questions...
I/flutter ( 5150): Okay... we fetch new...
I/flutter ( 5150): null
E/flutter ( 5150): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 5150): Receiver: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `questions` is null, so trying to iterate over it is going to throw an error.

Looking at your code, the root of the error seems to come from your `_fetchFromFirebase` method. In this case, you call `databaseReference.once()`, and in the `then` part you assign the result to `questionJson`. However, you never `await` on this call, so the `_fetchFromFirebase` method ends up returning the value of `questionJson` immediately after the call is made without waiting for it to finish. At that point, `questionJson` will be null, so that's what gets returned.

In general, I advise to not mix the `Future.then.catchError` pattern with the `async/await` pattern, as it can result in confusing logic that hides what is actually happening. As such, I'd recommend sticking just to `async/await` like so:

```dart
_fetchFromFirebase() async {
  try {
    final snapshot = await databaseReference.once();
    final questionJson = await snapshot.value;
    return questionJson;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return null;
  }
}
```